# netty based stress tool and connection counting

Tags: java, connection, netty, counter, stress-testing

I'm building a simple and fastest stress test tool for a web application. Requirements: highest number of outcoming http-requests (say, plain gets) from single node.

We used netty before and I choosed it for writing this simple test. It's a really simple and I finished with only 4 small classes extending netty api ([code is here](https://github.com/yetanothercoder/main/tree/master/src/main/java/ru/yetanothercoder/tests/stress)) and it gives about 30K rps on the localhost dev machine (linux).

The main limitation is the outgoing connection limit (open file/socket limit in linux), it's about 30-40K on my machine. You get `java.net.BindException` in this case. **Thus you have to limit the number of outgoing netty connections manually to prevent the performance degradation when you reach the limit**.

I implement this limit with counter and in the first version I incremented it in `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelConnected` and decremented in `future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().addListener` (see the code, comments in that places) and it didn't work: connections were not incremented as supposed and counter failed.

And only after I put increment near `bootstrap.connect`:

```
connected.incrementAndGet();
ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
```

and decrement in `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.messageReceived`:

```
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        // the same here - decrementing connections here is not fully fair but works!
        connected.decrementAndGet();
        e.getChannel().close();
    }
```

-it started working. The only issue - it's slightly unfair, because you can increment the counter but fail to connect or decrement and failed to disconnect after it.

So, why doesn't counter work in the correct version?

UPDATE: tried as suggested, inc/dec in `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelConnected`:

```
    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        // by logic you should count connection here, but in practice - it doesn't work
        connected.incrementAndGet();
        ctx.getChannel().getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                connected.decrementAndGet();
            }
        });

        e.getChannel().write(GET);
        sent.incrementAndGet();
    }
```

didn't work, again unpredictable numbers where sent > connected, e.g.:

```
client1 stat: connected=    0, sent=    0, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=    0, connects=0
client1 stat: connected=   11, sent= 4990, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=    0, connects=0
client1 stat: connected=    1, sent= 8591, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=    0, connects=0
client1 stat: connected=  459, sent=13064, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=    5, connects=0
client1 stat: connected= 1545, sent= 7234, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=  115, connects=0
client1 stat: connected=    0, sent=10037, ERRORS: timeouts=    0, binds=   80, connects=0
```

sadf

Answer (score 0):

A theory.

In your original version you decrement the *connected* counter for all connection attempts, event the failed ones. If you increment the counter in *channelConnected*() and add a decrementing listener to the ChannelCloseFuture and that point, I guess you will get a better result.

This is because

```
boostrap.connect().getChannel().getCloseFuture(...)
```

will always call operationComplete, even if the channel was never connected.

UPDATE:

To make sure that only connected channels are counted. In channelConnected() calback in STressClientHandler:

```
    connected.incrementAndGet();
    ctx.getChannel().getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
             connected.decrementAndGet();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you suggest to decrement a counter in ChannelCloseFuture? As I described I tried that as `future.getChannel().getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {...` with no luck. 
There is another option - serverside: `SimpleChannelHandler.channelClosed()`. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

You need ot increment the sent count in a ChannelFutureListener that is added to the ChannelFuture which was returned from the write(...) operation. Otherwise you will increment it even if the write is pending.

Comment: thanks, it's concerning a `sent` counter, but what about the established connection counter? that's what this question is about